# Ergodic behaviour for bounded random dynamical system

Tags: dynamical-systems, markov-chains, markov-process

Considering an iterated system described by
$$
X_n =\gamma_nX_{n-1} ,
$$
where $\gamma_i$ are non-negative i.i.d. variables. It is easy to show that the expectation will grow unbounded for $\mathbb E\gamma_i > 1$, but the trajectory that the  state  follows will  (with high probability) be given by
$$
X_n\sim e^{n\lambda+o(n)}
$$
where $\lambda$ is the Lyapunov exponent given by $\mathbb E\log\gamma$. Since $\log\mathbb E\gamma\geq\mathbb E\log \gamma$, divergence of the average process does not imply divergence of the instantaneous trajectory.

Now, consider the altered system
$$
X_n =\min\{\gamma_nX_{n-1},P\} 
$$
where $P$ is deterministic. It is clear now that the expectation will no longer grow unbounded. I am running simulations which  seem to suggest that (unlike for the unbounded system), when the Lyapunov exponent of the unbounded system is negative, $\mathbb E X_n$ decays asymptotically for the bounded system.

**My Question is:** Are there any theorems that state that, for a bounded Markovian system, if its unbounded counterpart has a negative Lyapunov exponents  then  the average of the bounded system will decay? Or something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $X$ denote the "unbounded" system $$X\to\gamma X,$$ with $E\gamma\gt1$ and $E\log\gamma\lt0$, then $X_n\to0$ almost surely and $E(X_n)\to\infty$. Let $X^P$ denote the "bounded" system $$X^P\to\min\{\gamma X^P,P\},$$ then one can couple $X$ and $X^P$ in such a way that, almost surely and for every $n$, $$X^P_n\leqslant\min\{X_n,P\}.$$ Then $X_n^P\to0$ almost surely because $X_n$ does, and $X_n^P\leqslant P$ almost surely and for every $n$, hence $$E(X_n^P)\to0.$$ To determine whether this convergence in the mean to $0$ is exponential or not, requires other arguments.

Comment: Using your notation, this is what I have. For $\lambda < 0$, 
$$\mathbb P \left[ e^{n\lambda-|o(n)|} \leq X^P_n \leq e^{n\lambda+|o(n)|}  \right] \geq 1- \delta_n,$$
where $\delta_n \to 0 $ as $n\to\infty$. Consequently, 
$$\mathbb E \left[ X_n^P \right] \leq e^{n\lambda+|o(n)|}(1-\delta_n) + P\delta_n \to 0.$$

Comment: how might we determine whether this convergence is exponential?